How to collect data in Framer and output it to the final screen
I’m currently building a simple test in Framer. Each question has three options, and each option has a score. There are 10 questions in total, and at the end, I want to sum up the scores and show the results divided into five levels. All the screens are designed, and I’ve used code overrides to add the scores to the buttons.
However, the issue I’m facing is connecting to the final screen. I understand how to do it with pure code, but I’m a bit confused about how to do it in Framer. There’s a loading page—should I put a component there and override the code for that, or should I override the code directly on the loading page itself? I feel like there might be a simpler and cleaner way to approach this.
Below is a portion of the code assigned to each button.
export function setScore1(Component): ComponentType {
    return (props) => {
        const [store, setStore] = useStore()

        return (
            <Component
                {...props}
                onTap={() => {
                    setStore({ score: store.score + 1 })
                }}
            />
        )
    }
}

I’m not sure if this is the right place to ask, but since there are a lot of experts here, I thought I’d give it a try. Any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
